# Do baby walkers help with reflux?

Tags: reflux

I have a very happy 4.5 month old with reflux.  He is trying his best to cope with it and does a very good job. He smiles all the time.  I noticed that he likes it when he sees your face and I know babies with reflux should not have too much pressure applied to their stomach, especially at this time when reflux is at it's peak (between 4 and 7 months), so I was curious if the baby walkers would be helpful in reducing reflux since the baby would be upright.  Has anyone had success with this?  I was thinking of a Bumbo seat as well, but I though that might cause pressure on their stomach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our pediatrician advised very strongly against using walkers. He said standing upright applies too much pressure on the baby's back if the baby isn't ready to be in this position.

Of course, this is the opinion of our pediatrician. I'm just communicating what he told us, so there's no authority at all in what I said. But at least is enough to conclude that you should talk to your pediatrician before buying a walker.

Comment: I have not used them in the past with my first child, I was more curious if it would help with alleviating reflux since pressure on the stomach would go down.  If it causes back issues, that is also a concern as well.

Comment: If your baby is on formula, there are some formulas that can prevent reflux. But it he/she is breastfeeding, than my guess is as good as yours.

Comment: Yes he is on Formula (Gerber Good Start).  We have been down this road (hospital) to find the right formula and that seems to be working the best.

Comment: I've also heard that walkers are not good, but more because it gets in the way of their learning to walk.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain about walkers, but I can say that a Bumbo chair will make it worse. Our 4 month old has just started into this reflux stage and putting him in it has, as you said, put more pressure on his stomach and caused a lot of spitting up.

Comment: That is why I want to avoid the Bumbo chair because I know it will put pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Holding the baby upright with its head on your shoulder and gently patting on the back till the baby burps (a small sound, you need to be listening) after every feed may help with this problem. 
Also they say the babies who vomit grow faster and healthier ... so nothing to worry about!